# after_sign_in_path_for action not loading Geokit in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, geokit

Im trying to refresh the Geokit location to session after the user sign in. I have the following code.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  session[:geo_location] = User.geocode(current_user.city)
end
```

But I'm getting the following error.

```
NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create

undefined method `model_name' for Geokit::GeoLoc:Class
```

Seems like Geokit is not loading before the devise controller. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `after_sign_in_path_for` must return a valid an url object and you are not doing it check its [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#after_sign_in_path_for-instance_method).